# Error al mostrar byteArray en TextView

Tags: java, android

hace años programe en VB6 un codificador personal que funciona muy bien, quisiera crear una app igual y descubri android studio, despues de aprender en kotlin y java lecciones basicas (me quede con java pq de kotlin ay poco, aunque me gusta mas kotlin). Este codigo que me muestra los resultados por consola bien, pero no consigo mostrarlo en un texview el simulador se cierra:

```
 package com.example.codf_cc;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etClave;
    EditText etR;
     Button btAceptar;
    byte []byteArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etClave= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etClave);
        btAceptar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAceptar);
        etR= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etR);

        btAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt=etClave.getText().toString();
                byte []byteArray=new byte[txt.length()];
                for (int i=0;i< byteArray.length;i++){
                    byteArray[i]=(byte)txt.charAt(i);
                    System.out.println(byteArray[i]);
                    
                }

            
           });
etR.setText(byteArray[1]);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `setText()` de un `TextView` es usado mostrar un texto pero si el valor que defines en este método es un entero, tratara de buscar el id de este recurso en el proyecto, si no existe este id en tu proyecto obtendrás un error.

En este caso estas tratando de mostrar un elemento de un byteArray, lo cual seguramente esta causando el problema:

```
etR.setText(byteArray[1]); //Cuidado!
```

Te sugiero asegures el valor que se va a mostrar sea un `String` de esta forma usando `String.valueOf(...)`:

```
etR.setText(String.valueOf(byteArray[1]));
```

Comment: Gracias, sospechaba que era por el tipo de variable de string a int pero no sabia en java como convertirlo, con  tu sugerencia String.valueOf anulo el tipo entero(int) y obligo a editar como string .gracias sigo aprendiendo.

Comment: Excelente!, Saludos